# Why my Internet Explorer take long time to fetch eBay login https page?

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, internet-explorer-8, bho

Why does my Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP, takes a longer time to fetch a `https` website, especially eBay login page?

In case of the codes, I am playing around with BHO to create my own plugin for IE. Which BHO function should I start to investigate? At first, I suspected `BeforeNavigate2`, but I found out, other website works well. But when going to eBay signin page, it takes a long time to fetch the site.

I would like to know how to solve this.

edit:
Here are the codes that I added.. I dont know maybe my code here slows things up :( need help..

```
void CWOTBar::BeforeNavigate2(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *url, VARIANT *Flags,
VARIANT *TargetFrameName, VARIANT *PostData, VARIANT *Headers,
VARIANT_BOOL *Cancel)
{   

//read path data from text file     
char str[256];  
fstream file_op("C:\\PROGRA~1\\logdata",ios::in);
file_op.getline(str, 256);
file_op.close();

char newPath[MAX_PATH];
int newCount = 0;

for(int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++)
 {
 if(str[i] == '\\')
   {
    newPath[newCount++] = str[i];
   }
   newPath[newCount++] = str[i];
 }
newPath[newCount]=0;

ofstream out("c:\\path.txt", ios::out | ios::out);
out.write(newPath, strlen(newPath));
out.close();

 string str3;
 ifstream in;
 in.open("c:\\path.txt");
 getline(in,str3);
 mycustompath = str3.c_str();      

  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secattr; 
  ZeroMemory(&secattr,sizeof(secattr));
  secattr.nLength = sizeof(secattr);
  secattr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
  HANDLE rPipe, wPipe;

  //Create pipes to write and read data
  CreatePipe(&rPipe,&wPipe,&secattr,0);

  STARTUPINFO sInfo; 
  ZeroMemory(&sInfo,sizeof(sInfo));
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo; 
  ZeroMemory(&pInfo,sizeof(pInfo));
  sInfo.cb=sizeof(sInfo);
  sInfo.dwFlags=STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  sInfo.hStdInput=NULL; 
  sInfo.hStdOutput=wPipe; 
  sInfo.hStdError=wPipe;

  CString one   = _T(" --url=");
  CString two(url->bstrVal);
  CString three = _T(" --out=\"") + mycustompath + _T("executables\\\\currentsnapshot.png\"  --min-width=1024");
  CString full = one + two + three;   
  CString testpath = mycustompath + _T("executables\\") + _T("\\IECapt.exe");

  SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};
  info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
  info.fMask  = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  info.lpFile = testpath;    
  info.lpParameters = full;
  info.nShow = SW_HIDE;

  if (ShellExecuteEx (&info))
    {
       WaitForSingleObject (info.hProcess, INFINITE);
    }

}
```

Comment: HTTPS has overheads and usually make page loads slower as opposed to fetching a page over HTTP.

Comment: It's possible the [tubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_of_tubes) to your house from eBay are clogged `;)`

Comment: But the slow is only for ebay login page. amazon login page also slow. but http sites are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many possible answers. One thing to be aware of is that https sites can not be cached by a proxy server in between you and the destination site, while http can. So it could be that the non SSL sites are faster because they are being served from a cache. Compounding this, and perhaps related to your code (indirectly) is the question of DNS lookup for a (non-cached) site. You might look into what DNS your code is relying on, and perhaps set the hosts file to see if that makes a noticeable difference.